# AngularJS: List comprehension in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, list-comprehension

I have following json structure:

```
$scope.info = [
              {
               "date": "01.10", "data": [
                    {'name': 'Кастусь', "behavior": "good", "attitude": "good"}
                    {'name': 'Андрэй', "behavior": "2 заўвагі па паводзінам", "attitude": "good"}]
               },
               {
               "date": "24.09", "data": [
                     {'name': 'Кастусь', "behavior": "good", "attitude": "good"},
                     {'name': 'Андрэй', "behavior": "3 заўвагі па паводзінам", "attitude": " good"}]
               }
 //...
```

I would like to iterate over all names. I tried python like `ng-repeat="name in record for record in info"` but it doesn't seem accurate. Could you assist, please?

Comment: I'd say create a custom filter takeout all the names & loop it through `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you map this to a flattened array that will give you easier sorting and filtering

```
$scope.info = data.reduce(function(a, c, i){
    return a.concat(c.data.map(function(item){
           item.date = c.date;
           return item
     });
},[])
```

Would return

```
$scope.info = [

   {'name': 'Кастусь', "behavior": "good", "attitude": "good", "date": "01.10"},
   {'name': 'Андрэй', "behavior": "2 заўвагі па паводзінам", "attitude": "good", "date": "01.10"}
   {'name': 'Кастусь', "behavior": "good", "attitude": "good", "date": "24.09"},
   {'name': 'Андрэй', "behavior": "3 заўвагі па паводзінам", "attitude": " good", "date": "24.09"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

For Angular, you'll need to do:

```
<div ng-repeat="infoItem in info">
    <div ng-repeat="dataItem in infoItem.data">
        <div ng-bind="datItem.name"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is memory intensive, so I would say iterate over the array in your Javascript and create a new scope variable with the flattened structure, and iterate over that in your HTML

You could do something like this:

```js
var info = [{
  "date": "01.10",
  "data": [{
    'name': 'Кастусь',
    "behavior": "good",
    "attitude": "good"
  }, {
    'name': 'Андрэй',
    "behavior": "2 заўвагі па паводзінам",
    "attitude": "good"
  }]
}, {
  "date": "24.09",
  "data": [{
    'name': 'Кастусь',
    "behavior": "good",
    "attitude": "good"
  }, {
    'name': 'Андрэй',
    "behavior": "3 заўвагі па паводзінам",
    "attitude": " good"
  }]
}];


var names = [];

info.map(function(infoItem) {
  return infoItem.data.map(function(dataItem) {
    names.push(dataItem.name);
  });
});
console.log(names);
```

And bind the `ng-repeat` like this:

```
    <div ng-repeat="name in names" ng-bind="name"></div>
```